# String generation in c#

Tags: c#, .net

How can I create an string (AB180951127010) in c# in following format ? Please take current date in order to determine the same.

```
AB  18  095 11     27   010
```

Constant     YY      DDD     HH      MM      SSS

I was trying to come up with a method to generate string in above format but somehow it never generated in that format.

```
 private string Id()
        {

            return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}", ConstantCode, DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.DayOfYear, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
        }
```

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following.

Note: I do not know why second requires 3 digits.

[image]

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Id());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static private string Id()
    {    
        var dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
        return string.Format("{0} {1:yy} {2:D3} {1:hh} {1:mm} 0{1:ss}", 
           "AB", dateTimeNow, dateTimeNow.DayOfYear);
    }
}
```

You can read more about [String Format for DateTime](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/).

Comment: @DavidG Good catch. I updated the answer.

Comment: Minor tweak, pretty sure OP needs 3 digits for the day of year